# Allow Comments on Deleted Answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-answers

Somebody deleted an answer because of an incorrect comment, and I wanted to put a comment on there telling him that the original commenter was wrong, and that he should undelete his answer (which had 4 upvotes at the time).  I had to edit the answer to put "Why was this deleted?!" to get my message through.

Comment: While I agree a comment is a "politer" way of notifying the user, the fact that you can see the deleted answer means you have more than 10K rep so you can edit the post (as you did), so I can see this getting [status-declined]

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158439/166155

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129068/allow-comments-on-your-own-deleted-posts

Answer (score 2):

This is a good idea, especially since comments on one's posts result in you being notified, while edits do not.

*Edit to prove you get notified*

Comment: You do get notified of edits. They appear in the "Revisions" tab on your recent activity pages.

Comment: @ChrisF: But you have to actively look for them. There is not much attention brought to edits and they are easily missed.

Comment: But has the envelope icon ever changed to highlight based on revisions? That's what one particular user thinks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38059/me-wanna-no-envelope @chr

Comment: *huh*. Now I'm not so sure. I can't say I recall getting a revision notification; maybe I missed it because I just look at what got upvoted recently.

Answer (score 1):

Even if we did allow this, I'm pretty sure the notification code is only checking posts where `DeletionDate = null` -- that's a routine thing to include on every query we make, and deviating from it in this one area would be awkward.

Comment: Does this mean the author won't receive notification about an edit either?

Answer (score -12):

I think a better idea would be to un-delete all of the answers and questions. I know I've personally had a few of mine closed when they shouldn't have been and they're are probably a lot of other questions that were mistakenly closed too.

Comment: "when they shouldn't have been"... do you still believe that??

Comment: Yes. We should never delete people's content unless it is illegal. Otherwise it makes me think twice about posting anything of considerable size here vs on my personal blog, since here it might be completely delete. Then let up an downvotes decide what is better.