# Allow comments on your own deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-answers

I never got notified that this answer of mine has been deleted. (I don't really care about it anymore, since the issue is resolved, but it added something to the discussion that was not present before).
I realized it due to new activity on the post:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125552/167500

I couldn't find @random on the chat.
So, I would like to add a comment on my own post to explain why my post was an answer, but I can't.

As of now, it is possible to edit those posts, but not to comment on it (for example to ping a mod that deleted an answer without a note and without an obvious reason, so he can see my explanations).

Would it be possible to also allow one to comment on their own deleted post?

Comment: I'd only allow, at best, *one* comment. Otherwise, not you since I know you as a user, but think about it: how many users will start commenting and complaining for every single deleted answer?

Comment: New users don't even know the @ping syntax, I don't think we would be bothered too much with users complaining for no reason. In this case it was a real answer, even if one needs to think 2 seconds about it.

Comment: Ok, I modified a little bit my intentions, but it does not change the problem that occurs with adding the feature.

Comment: Always waiting on Wave to answer any questions

Comment: @random: Now I can ping you :-) I added some comments by editing my deleted post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea. The main case where I think commenting would be used is to carry on arguing (and guarantee having the last word).

There's already a mechanism for escalating a dispute over a deletion, via flagging or questions here on meta. That's fairly hard/expensive in terms of time/effort and severity, but that's a good thing: it gives time to cool down (hopefully for a constructive disucssion if one is justified) and eliminates the trivial pointless ones.

If you fix a post via editing then flag stating such. If you think a deletion was a mistake then flag with a convincing reason. If you think there's a broader discussion to be had then bring it up on meta. All of those can be handled by any moderator. (If you think the deletion was reasonable then there's nothing more to be done and nothing to be gained by commenting further)

Comment: I just want a friendly way to communicate with @random nothing more.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez The point is not you, but all of the users that will be affected by such a feature that may misuse and abuse it. I wouldn't be surprised if we started receiving notifications one after another.

Comment: @Alenanno: I know, but I wanted to raise the question. I **would like to be notified** when I made an error by deleting an answer. Even though I could be bothered by some sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say +- every single person would want a 1 on 1 explanation why *their* post was deleted... 
You asked specifically for the mod that deleted it - but would *any* mod's explanation suffice?  After all we are all on the same team, right?

I'm speculating here (as a muggle sopedian) that allowing comments on deleted questions (even if only available for the OP) would create a monumental amount of work/noise for the moderators.

They *are* community elected moderators and as such the *community* has put their faith in them; Entrusting them to moderate the content of the site with precision and and super-duper-mod-tricks (that we are not supposed to know about).

Sure you can come and post a question here on meta asking why your post was closed - and you'll probably get an answer **but** not always by a moderator and possibly even by a random moderator that happened to be passing by ;)

From my short experience on the site I have not seen many moderator blunders (however I believe that such a paradox *could* theoretically exist).  In most cases that I have witnessed the final answer comes down to quoting [a portion of the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) and that's the end of the story.

Comment: To answer the first question: Because the point was to give private feedback to the moderator. Moderation without feedback is not good IMO.

Comment: You do get feedback - if the moderator feels the need to.  If you want to contact a specific moderator you could always flag it and mention the moderators name in the custom text.